# What's the syntax of this line of code in the function "normalize" in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

The code is like this:

```
scale = (dmax - dmin)*(smax - smin > DBL_EPSILON ? 1./(smax - smin) : 0);
```

What does the syntax in `1./` mean? Does it mean an operator `./` or mean a number `1.0`?

Comment: It means `1.0`, there is no operator `./` that I know of.

Answer (score 3):

you can translate it to:

```
if (smax - smin > DBL_EPSILON)
    scale = (dmax - dmin) / (smax-smin);
else
    scale = 0;
```

and yes, 1./x is the same as 1.0/x (also, there's no ./ operator in c++)

Comment: thanks your answer. never hear this syntax before, could you tell me where can I find the definition of 1.

Comment: it is helpful for me, nice site.